# Background image with linear gradient shows in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image, linear-gradients

```css
.hero {

  display: grid; 
  place-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 33%,
      hsla(224, 62%, 29%, 0.9),
      rgba(228, 24, 27, 0.8)
    ),
    url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
       <div class="hero-box">
        <h2 class="hero-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facilis
          similique cupiditate temporibus excepturi, consectetur, expedita
          nisi in! Distinctio, quibusdam
          exercitationem placeat fugiat excepturi dolore nihil! Sint saepe
          quidem voluptatum?
        </h2>
        <div class="hero-btn-container">
        <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Visit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In a section of my project I have a background image set in CSS, on this image I set a linear gradient: everything works fine in Safari but NOT in Chrome: there the gradient shows correctly but the background image is not visible at all, why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any elements with class hero in your html. Please consider reviewing and fixing your code to someone could reproduce issue

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to copy paste the opening div with the hero class. Now I edited

Comment: Please could you make your code into  a runnable snippet and check that it shows the problem because I cannot reproduce it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: Did it. The gradient is visible but the background image is visible only In Safari but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Added a div with `class` `hero` and imported an image.

```css
.hero {
  display: grid; 
  place-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 33%,
      hsla(224, 62%, 29%, 0.9),
      rgba(228, 24, 27, 0.8)
    ),
    url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
    <div class="hero-box">
        <h2 class="hero-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facilis
          similique cupiditate temporibus excepturi, consectetur, expedita aut
          molestias fuga unde id nam doloremque laborum adipisci enim soluta ut
          nisi in! Distinctio, quibusdam
          exercitationem placeat fugiat excepturi dolore nihil! Sint saepe
          quidem voluptatum?
        </h2>
        <div class="hero-btn-container">
        <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Visit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero"></div>
    </div>
```